# Beamer query, center justify \frametitle

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, frame-title

In `beamer`, to center justify the frame-title, one uses this:

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
```

This is what I have as default:

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\textbf{\insertframetitle} \par }
```

When I add the `[default][center]` options, and have this:

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]{\textbf{\insertframetitle} \par }
```

It won't compile with a `missing /begin{document}` error message. I guess I am not respecting some syntax rules.... Can anyone help, how do I modify my existing default setup, to have the `frametitle` center justified.

Cheers,

Jat

Comment: `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\centering\textbf{\insertframetitle}\par}`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have centered bold-faced frame titles, you can use

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
```

to center the titles and

```
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}
```

to have boldface font. A complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A test frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]