# How do I horizontally center the title in a slide

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, frame-title

How do I put the title in the center of a slide:

I have the following code:

```
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

% Uncomment these lines for an automatically generated outline.
%\begin{frame}{Outline}
%  \tableofcontents
%\end{frame}

\section{Outline}
\begin{frame}{Outline}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Semidefinite Relaxations over Rotation Matrices 
  \item Attitude Estimation of Satellite
  \item Future Work
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
```

The following is its image. How do I put the "Outline" in the center?  (i.e. just horizontally shift "Outline" to the center.)

[image]

Comment: For just one frame, or all of them?

Comment: @Werner   For all of pages' title. I want all titles to be in the center.

Comment: See also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225061/beamer-query-center-justify-frametitle

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Set the template for `frametitle` to include a `center`ed horizontal alignment:

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
```

Here is a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94159/5764
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Outline}

  Some regular content.

  \begin{itemize}
    \item Semidefinite Relaxations over Rotation Matrices 
    \item Attitude Estimation of Satellite
    \item Future Work
  \end{itemize}

\end{frame}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am sorry, but how can I center the title in the main title page in [this MWE](https://pastebin.com/FhwCTPZL)?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: You can use `\title{\makebox[\linewidth]{<title>}}` - the title doesn't seem to be used elsewhere, so setting it in a box in the aforementioned way will centre it.

Comment: When revisiting your answer to my question, it fails to generate a multi-lined centered title for this [MWE](https://pastebin.com/WgY2nuKk), so what is wrong here?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: For that you can try using `\parbox{\linewidth}` instead of `\makebox[\linewidth]`.